# Do you really need a Text attribute in an ASP.NET Label?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between the following?

```
<asp:Label runat="server">Hello World</asp:Label>

<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hello World"></asp:Label>
```

---

**UPDATED:**

If they are exactly the same then why does

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
There were <%#transactionCount%> transactions today
</asp:Label>
```

bind correctly when using single-value databinding and displays the correct value for transactionCount, while...

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="There were <%#transactionCount%> transactions today">
</asp:Label>
```

does not show a value for transactionCount in the page?

---

**UPDATED AGAIN:**

I understand the points being made about using the Literal controls. I shall slap my face accordingly - but it still doesn't solve the problem - though is perhaps getting closer to a solution.

If I use...

```
<asp:Literal ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%#transactionCount%>"></asp:Literal>
```

...I see transactionCount's value show up in the web page.

On the other hand, if I put any character or word in front of the single-value databinding field e.g.

```
<asp:Literal ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="No. <%#transactionCount%>"></asp:Literal>
```

...transactionCount does not appear.

Comment: They are the same Joe. The parser treats them the same.

Comment: You really should use a literal for this - as another poster says, Labels are for labelling form fields.  It's not semantically correct in the context you supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will render the same in your final HTML.  However the `Text` attribute is useful for programmatically setting the displayed text in your code behind.

Comment: ..and adds consistency with the rest of the server controls

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I'm not finding they operate the same for single-value databinding. I've updated my question above

Answer (score 2):

Yes, outside of satisfying the ITextControl interface. Remember that 99% of developers use `Labels` wrong--one generally should be using `Literals` to hold output, if not just `<%# Databind() %>`. You don't need a server-side span for most things.

Where one should use a label is to create a label field in your form:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="LabelForFirstName" Text="First Name:" AssociatedControlID="firstname />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="FirstName" />
```

Gives one a label tied to the first name tag and semantically correct HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the text as Hello World you cannot change its value progamatically from your code-bhind file.

Whereas,  woukd let you change the value as mytxt.Text = "New text"

But they will be rendered the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why they are different is to support [implicit localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(VS.80).aspx). In the resource file you specify ID.Property (i.e. Label1.Text).